# R Shiny keep title and text box updated

Tags: r, shiny

In a Shiny app I want the title to be a default title each time the user changes the plot type but I would like the user to be able to manually change the values in the text box and have the plot title update as well. Essentially this amounts to:

#### Rules

1) Every time the user changes the plot type in the pull-down use the default title and update the text box with the title.

2) Every time the user makes changes in the text box replace the title with the text in the text box.

#### As an example:

1) If the user selects a plot type "n" then the title will be "Plot type is n" and the text box will be the same.

2) Then if the user types in the text box "Blah, blah" the plot title becomes "Blah blah".

3) Then when the user changes the plot type to "p" the title becomes "Plot type is p"

And so on, suggestions?

```
library(shiny)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$plot <- renderUI({

    h <- input$height
    w <- input$width
    list(
      tags$h3("Plot information"),
      renderPlot({

        # if input$title has been changed by the user update the
        # plot title to input$title, otherwise use default_title

        default_title <- paste("Plot type is", input$type)
        updateTextInput(session, "title", value=default_title)
        plot(1:10, main=default_title, type=input$type)

      })
    )
  })

} 

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$div(class="panel-body",

           textInput("title", "Give a title",  "This is my initital title"),
           selectInput("type", "choose type", choices=c("p", "n", "s"), selected="s")
  ),

  uiOutput("plot")

)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Do you want the plot title to change when the `selectInput("type")` is changed, or when the user types directly into the `textInput( )` box?

Comment: Thanks for the updated - it's much clearer what you're asking now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below should work. I separated the logic to two different `observe`

```
library(shiny)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  # This updates both the text input and the plot when type changes
  observe({
    type <- input$type
    default_title <- paste("Plot type is", input$type)
    updateTextInput(session, "title", value = default_title)
    output$plot <- renderPlot({
      plot(1:10, main = default_title, type = input$type)
    })
  })

  # This updates the plot when input changes
  observe({
    title <- input$title
    output$plot <- renderPlot({
      plot(1:10, main = title, type = input$type)
    })
  })

  output$plotInfo <- renderUI({
    list(tags$h3("Plot information"))
  })

}


ui <- fluidPage(

  tags$div(
    class = "panel-body",
    textInput("title", "Give a title",  "This is my initital title"),
    selectInput(
      "type",
      "choose type",
      choices = c("p", "n", "s"),
      selected = "s"
    )
  ),

  uiOutput("plotInfo"),
  plotOutput("plot")

)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```